# How to pick image or video in flutter from one place?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using image_picker plugin to pick images and videos but in the plugin example you must select that you want to pick image or video from gallery . So is there is another way to show both together in one place ?

```
 final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
// Pick an image
final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: 
ImageSource.gallery);

// Pick a video
final XFile? image = await _picker.pickVideo(source: 
ImageSource.gallery);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dependent on the `plugin` and its capabilities that you use. If it does not provide what you need, either you need to develop your `plugin` or try to use another one. If this `plugin` is changeable for you, please take a look following solutions:

1- [wechat_assets_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/wechat_assets_picker):

```
final List<AssetEntity>? assets = await AssetPicker.pickAssets(
  context,
  maxAssets: 2,
  requestType: RequestType.all,
  pickerTheme: appTheme,
  textDelegate: EnglishTextDelegate(),
);
```

It provides different `RequestType` like `audio`, `video`, `common`, `image`, and `all`.

2- [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager):

```
final assetPathEntityList =
  await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(type: RequestType.all);
```

This plugin provides different `RequestType` like `audio`, `video`, `common`, `image`, and `all` too. The difference is there is no `UI` widget. Therefore you need to develop your `UI` and connect with this `plugin`.

If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one thing, If you need to use **image_picker** then you can do following,

1. Give pin icon widget where you want to access media.
2. Show dialog on it which says, either select video or image.
3. Handle your methods accordingly.

[image: Like this]